# Failed to consume a message from destination Queue - Solace

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud-stream, solace, solace-mq

I am using Spring cloud stream 2021.0.2 to consume messages from solace queue, when some messages are sent , I can see the message gets spooled continuously in the queue but It is not coming inside the application and processed because of the below exception. we are NOT setting value for `deliveryAttempt` anywhere within our microservice. Please help

```
023-04-13 16:21:39.086 WARN 27352 --- [pool-3-thread-5] s.b.i.RetryableInboundXMLMessageListener : Failed to consume a message from destination QUE_173707_PLATFORM_EVENT_LOGGING_DEV - attempt 3

2023-04-13 16:21:39.086 WARN 27352 --- [pool-3-thread-5] s.b.i.RetryableInboundXMLMessageListener : Failed to consume a message from destination QUE_173707_PLATFORM_EVENT_LOGGING_DEV - attempt 3

2023-04-13 16:21:39.086 WARN 27352 --- [pool-3-thread-5] s.b.i.RetryableInboundXMLMessageListener : Failed to consume a message from destination QUE_173707_PLATFORM_EVENT_LOGGING_DEV - attempt 3

2023-04-13 16:21:39.086 WARN 27352 --- [pool-3-thread-5] s.b.i.RetryableInboundXMLMessageListener : Failed to consume a message from destination QUE_173707_PLATFORM_EVENT_LOGGING_DEV - attempt 3

2023-04-13 16:21:39.087 WARN 27352 --- [pool-3-thread-5] s.b.i.RetryableInboundXMLMessageListener : Failed to consume a message from destination QUE_173707_PLATFORM_EVENT_LOGGING_DEV - attempt 3

2023-04-13 16:21:39.087 ERROR 27352 --- [pool-3-thread-5] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler  : org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Incorrect type specified for header 'deliveryAttempt'. Expected [class java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger] but actual type is [class java.lang.String]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Incorrect type specified for header 'deliveryAttempt'. Expected [class java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger] but actual type is [class java.lang.String]
```

Comment: FYI - if others find this in the future it looks like this discussion is happening over here: https://solace.community/discussion/1732/failed-to-consume-a-message-from-destination-queue#latest